# Android App using wifimanager in OnTouch event

Tags: android

I have one class defined as

```
public class LearningMap extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
```

It is defined inside the `onTouch` method.

I am tring to use wifimanager by calling:

```
myWifiManager.startScan();
```

I defined

```
myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

inside the `onCreate`

I got the following error

> 02-05 23:51:21.136: E/AndroidRuntime(17542):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

at that line where I used myWifiManager.startScan();  inside OnTouch method

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

What about the permissions? Did you add `INTERNET`, `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have figured out . I should have used the setontouchlistener in my view class not in the listener class

Answer (score 0):

Try catching and logging the exception, it will most likely tell you if there are any permissions missing.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

try
{
    wifiManager.startScan();
}
catch( SecurityException e )
{
    Log.e("WifiTest", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

The first exception line in LogCat will probably be something like

> 02-05 19:13:24.065: E/WifiTest(19131): WifiService: Neither user 10123
>   nor current process has `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`.

This can be easily solved by [requesting the correct permissions from your manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions).

Note that retrieving the scan results through getScanResults(), which you'll most likely want to do, will additionally require the `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permission.

Comment: Thanks I did set the permission . I have figured out